# Java application design for an IDS

Tags: java, mysql, architecture

I am working on a java project with other students at the university that has to detect intrusions within a system. 
This system tracks data forwarding of nodes ...
So we have a big number of nodes that forward packets from a source to a destination, for example a node (A) wants to send a packet to node (D) and (D) is not in the radio range of (A), so (A) send it to (B),(B) to (C)  and (C) send it to the destination (D).

((A) -> (B) -> (C) -> (D)).

We use a MySQL DB to store the tracked data. Our table looks like:

id, source, destination, sender, receiver, dataContent, hash, timestamp

My question is : how can we make sure that a packet sent by a source (A) came with success to the destination (D) within a time X ... and maybe is there any better approache for this kind of problems ... ?

Comment: I don't think the idea of your assignment is to get the problems solved by other people on stackoverflow. Please see your textbooks for pointers on how to get started with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Take a looks at the TCP network protocol.  It was developed for this exact purpose, and it's design elements have been fairly well proven out over the years :-)